# entity hasoptional foreign keyone to one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this class:

```
public class CommunityUser : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public int ForumPostsNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

How to use entity framework mapping to say that a CommunityUser has an optional CustomerId that is a foreign key on the Customer Table?

Answer (score 1):

You must make your foreign key nullable by making it `int?`

```
public class CommunityUser : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public int ForumPostsNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ok but how to use the key words: HasOptional and HasForeignKey ?